# The wave header is corrupt error when playing wav file from array object vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, audio, resources, playback

I am trying to build an application that says a number, for example 123 --> "one, two, three" from wav sounds.
I am able to play the same wav file several times by using below command without any problem:

```vb
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.xxx, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

but when I put the object into an array like this

```vb
wav_files() As Object =
    {0,
    My.Resources.xxx,
    My.Resources.yyy,
    My.Resources.zzz,
    }
```

then I tried to call the same index in the array two times:

```vb
My.Computer.Audio.Play(wav_files(2), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
My.Computer.Audio.Play(wav_files(2), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

and kept getting an error:

> The wave header is corrupt.

I need to put those wav files to be indexed so I can call them on my conversion function NUMBERS --> SOUND

Am I doing it right? Is there any other idea so my resource has index file ordered.

Comment: Don't declare your array as type `Object`.  Declare it as the actual type of those resource properties. That's probably `Byte` array or some type of `Stream`.  If you want an "empty" element at the start then set it to `Nothing`.

Comment: When you do it using an array, does the issue occur on the first or second time you play the sound?

Comment: @jmcilhinney i still got the same error if i call the sound twice : 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
The wave header is corrupt.

Comment: That isn't an answer to my question.  Please read the words.  When you execute the third code snippet from your question, is the exception thrown on the first line or the second line?

Comment: oh sorry for not reading well, the error was thrown on second line, ONLY IF i call same index, 

but if i call 
index(1)
index(2)
index(3)
.
.
index(n)
everything was fine.. 

Thank your for prompt reply..

Comment: What data type are your resource properties?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, it's audio file, .wav

Comment: That's NOT an answer to my question.  There is no such data type.  That's the type of files that you added as resources.  It is NOT the data type of the properties you're using.  I repeat, what data type are the resource properties you're using, i.e. `My.Resources.xxx`, etc?

Comment: Try changing AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete to AudioPlayMode.Background/ It might be that the handle to the resources have not been released because of the intervals between calls.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b, surely that would make matters worse.  If you proceed to the next call without waiting for the sound to finish playing then you pretty much guarantee that any handle that wasn't released previously definitely won't be.  At best, you'd end up with the same sound being played multiple times over each other.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b 
the same error occurred..

Comment: @jmcilhinney UnmanagedMemoryStream, is that the datatype ?

Comment: Yes, that is the data type.  My suspicion is that the stream position, i.e. the next byte that will be read from the stream, is at the end after the sound is played.  When you try to play it again, the stream starts reading from the end of the data and there is obviously not a valid WAV sound to be read from there, hence the exception.  Try resetting the position after playing the sound.  That would something like `wav_files(2).Position = 0` or `wav_files(2).Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed as I expected, i.e. the stream position needs to be reset.  I just tried this and it worked as expected:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private sounds As UnmanagedMemoryStream() = {Nothing,
                                                 My.Resources.First,
                                                 My.Resources.Second,
                                                 My.Resources.Third}

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(sounds(1), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
        sounds(1).Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(sounds(1), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Given that your intent is to play sounds by array index, I'd probably go with this sort of thing:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private sounds As UnmanagedMemoryStream() = {Nothing,
                                                 My.Resources.First,
                                                 My.Resources.Second,
                                                 My.Resources.Third}

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        PlaySound(1)
        PlaySound(1)
        PlaySound(1)
        PlaySound(2)
        PlaySound(2)
        PlaySound(2)
        PlaySound(3)
        PlaySound(3)
        PlaySound(3)
    End Sub

    Private Sub PlaySound(index As Integer)
        Dim sound = sounds(index)

        My.Computer.Audio.Play(sound, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
        sound.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    End Sub

End Class
```

That worked for me as is.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Ok, here's what worked:

```
Dim wavs As New List(Of Byte())

wavs.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(<PATH_TO_YOUR_SOUND_FILE_1>))
wavs.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(<PATH_TO_YOUR_SOUND_FILE_2>))
wavs.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(<PATH_TO_YOUR_SOUND_FILE_3>))

My.Computer.Audio.Play(wavs(0), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
My.Computer.Audio.Play(wavs(0), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
My.Computer.Audio.Play(wavs(0), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

Or using Resources:

```
Using stream As System.IO.Stream = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream(<STRING NAME OF RESOURCE WITHOUT EXTENSION>)
    Dim buffer(stream.Length) As Byte
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, stream.Length - 1)
    wavs.Add(buffer)
End Using

My.Computer.Audio.Play(wavs(0), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
My.Computer.Audio.Play(wavs(0), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
My.Computer.Audio.Play(wavs(0), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

Comment: you play different file in sequence, what i want to do is play same file several time like this : 
My.Computer.Audio.Play(wavFiles(0), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
My.Computer.Audio.Play(wavFiles(0), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
My.Computer.Audio.Play(wavFiles(0), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)

still got same error..

Comment: Oh sorry. Didn't see that.

Comment: hi this is interesting, is the <PATH_TO_YOUR_SOUND_FILE_1> means the directory of the sound file ? or referring to my resources ?

Comment: The full path to your sound file (including filename). But this way, you'll have to include the actual files to your installation instead of as resources, if you don't mind this type of deployment.